# Count number of download of file through repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, repeater, datarepeater

I want to count number of download of particular file in asp.net,
I am using repeater and file source is 
    `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("source")`.

but problem is how to pass file id,
can it possible pass two     `CommandArgument` in repeater.
click here.. [CommandArgument in repeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJhUD.png)

Comment: No, you can't have two `CommandArgument` in repeater but you can pass multiple eval field in one command argument and at CS you can split them up.

Comment: @Suprabhat I think you meant to say "you **can't** have two CommandArgument"

Comment: :) Already edited but thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one as **CommandArgument='<%#Eval("source")%>'** and Second as **CommandName='<%#Eval("fileId")%>'**. get command name value on code behind same as a command argument.

Comment: @kaushik-mehta I want to pass three arguments. Do you think yours is a viable solution?